# DKIM - body hash did not verify

Tags: c#, smtp, dkim

I'm trying to send a very simple email to gmail (or any other email provider) with DKIM header.

The result in gmail is: dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)

I assume that the body hash isn't correct.
I made the body super simple and still get the same error.

Here is the SMTP data string:

```
DKIM-Signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha1; q=dns/txt; s=default;\r\n c=simple/simple; d=cumulo9.com; h=Date:From:To:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding;\r\n t=1489977499; bh=rtE3fSBFa/HdaPcuGaMM2mZVL7Mljo9sPTNOBjmNBdgIpGYh+ukt71Joc/qFd/nY70yn/hW0nASN+SZARGY2ri0ymA6NUrCIcSX7yJxJ6MkO78cyGZUoHY6Y+kOsDfCUcH5ANHJs88iUtu4IviWP4vWHXBd/tqP9k7Q+UKaC+m4=;\r\n b=klwC+c8qFKVD32SK22K04/YID+TerTvd26+VnlTljNA3fOEVbi2YlvTFo5LM1VksmO08hu5iJfwmF/3GgSEOnGT3mrzXxofjPbvIWU181zluxObNt8FwrP0kCIUskJEQz2SPF1VzaMQ8QvVchnkEFYrW9Pvssk6hunNr8J6CGrc=\r\nDate: Mon, 20 Mar 2017 15:38:17 +1300\r\nFrom: <leo@cumulo9.com>\r\nTo: leo@cumulo9.com\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\nhelloleo\r\n.
```

The only thing that I can come up with is that there must be an error in the body hash code.

```
public string SignBody(string body)
    {
        var cb = body + "\r\n";

        IPrivateKeySigner _privateKeySigner = new MailPost.DKIM.PrivateKeySigner(PrivateKey);

        byte[] defaultEncoding = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cb);

        byte[] hash = _privateKeySigner.Sign(defaultEncoding, SigningAlgorithm.RSASha1);

        string bodyHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

        return bodyHash;
    }
```

Function in the "PrivateKeySigner" class:

```
public byte[] Sign(byte[] data, SigningAlgorithm algorithm)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        using (var rsa = OpenSslKey.DecodeRSAPrivateKey(m_key))
        {
            byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(data, GetHashName(algorithm));

            return signature;

        }
    }
```

Function in the "OpenSslKey" class:

```
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider DecodeRSAPrivateKey(byte[] privkey)
    {
        if (privkey == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("privkey");
        }

        byte[] MODULUS, E, D, P, Q, DP, DQ, IQ;

        // ---------  Set up stream to decode the asn.1 encoded RSA private key  ------
        //var mem = new MemoryStream(privkey);
        using (var binr = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(privkey)))    //wrap Memory Stream with BinaryReader for easy reading
        {

            ushort twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
            if (twobytes == 0x8130) //data read as little endian order (actual data order for Sequence is 30 81)
                binr.ReadByte(); //advance 1 byte
            else if (twobytes == 0x8230)
                binr.ReadInt16(); //advance 2 bytes
            else
                return null;

            twobytes = binr.ReadUInt16();
            if (twobytes != 0x0102) //version number
                return null;
            byte bt = binr.ReadByte();
            if (bt != 0x00)
                return null;


            //------  all private key components are Integer sequences ----
            int elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
            MODULUS = binr.ReadBytes(elems);

            elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
            E = binr.ReadBytes(elems);

            elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
            D = binr.ReadBytes(elems);

            elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
            P = binr.ReadBytes(elems);

            elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
            Q = binr.ReadBytes(elems);

            elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
            DP = binr.ReadBytes(elems);

            elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
            DQ = binr.ReadBytes(elems);

            elems = GetIntegerSize(binr);
            IQ = binr.ReadBytes(elems);


            // ------- create RSACryptoServiceProvider instance and initialize with public key -----
            var RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            var RSAparams = new RSAParameters
                                {
                                    Modulus = MODULUS,
                                    Exponent = E,
                                    D = D,
                                    P = P,
                                    Q = Q,
                                    DP = DP,
                                    DQ = DQ,
                                    InverseQ = IQ
                                };
            RSA.ImportParameters(RSAparams);
            return RSA;

        }
    }
```

Code for GetIntegerSize():

```
private static int GetIntegerSize([NotNull]BinaryReader binr)
    {
        if (binr == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("binr");
        }

        int count;
        byte bt = binr.ReadByte();
        if (bt != 0x02)     //expect integer
            return 0;
        bt = binr.ReadByte();

        if (bt == 0x81)
            count = binr.ReadByte();    // data size in next byte
        else
            if (bt == 0x82)
            {
                byte highbyte = binr.ReadByte();
                byte lowbyte = binr.ReadByte();
                byte[] modint = { lowbyte, highbyte, 0x00, 0x00 };
                count = BitConverter.ToInt32(modint, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                count = bt;     // we already have the data size
            }



        while (binr.ReadByte() == 0x00)
        {   //remove high order zeros in data
            count -= 1;
        }
        binr.BaseStream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);       //last ReadByte wasn't a removed zero, so back up a byte
        return count;
    }
```

Currently I'm really stuck with this problem and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm not able to use other libraries like "MimeKit" because of the nature of you project. If you need any more information about this problem then please let me know and I will do my best to provide it to you.

Thanks heaps for helping me out.

Comment: Why can't you use MimeKit? What is the nature of the project that makes it unusable to you? MimeKit is MIT licensed which means you can use it in proprietary software or open source software. There's no licensing fees. It works on .NET Core. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Our existing software already sends emails with all it's bells and whistles it needs and has been developed very carefully to do exactly what we want. I'm not allowed to change all of this to include MimeKit just because I have a problem with DKIM. Can you please help me with the question how to implement DKIM instead of using MimeKit?

Comment: MimeKit was designed so you could use it w/o needing to use MailKit (i.e. you could use it with your own SMTP library) - so I guess what you meant to say was that it's not due to the nature of MimeKit, but rather due to the nature of *your* project :)

Comment: What's your code for `GetIntegerSize(BinaryReader)`?

Comment: I have changed my question to include the GetIntegerSize(BinaryReader) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have several problems (and here you thought you only had 1!).

First, how did you determine the `body` of the message? Is this just the string that you are setting on the `MailMessage` as its body? If so, that's not likely to work unless you are only sending very simple text messages (and even then... it might not, depending on whether or not `MailMessage` decides it needs to encode your text using, for example, the `base64` or `quoted-printable` encoding). You need to make sure that the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` gets applied *before* you generate the body hash.

Secondly, did you remember to transform the body text using the `Simple` body canonicalization rules described in [rfc6376, section 3.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.4.3)? It looks to me like you are just tacking on a `"\r\n"` but that's not what the rules say to do.

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can try using a library like [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) to construct and DKIM-sign your message like so:

```
var message = new MimeMessage ();
message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("", "leo@cumulo9.com"));
message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("", "leo@cumulo9.com"));
message.Body = new TextPart ("plain") { Text = "helloleo" };

var headers = new HeaderId[] { HeaderId.Date, HeaderId.From, HeaderId.To, HeaderId.ContentType, HeaderId.ContentTransferEncoding };
var headerAlgorithm = DkimCanonicalizationAlgorithm.Simple;
var bodyAlgorithm = DkimCanonicalizationAlgorithm.Simple;
var signer = new DkimSigner ("privatekey.pem", "cumulo9.com", "default") {
    SignatureAlgorithm = DkimSignatureAlgorithm.RsaSha1,
    QueryMethod = "dns/txt",
};

// Prepare the message body to be sent over a 7bit transport (such as
// older versions of SMTP).
// Note: If the SMTP server you will be sending the message over supports
// the 8BITMIME extension, then you can use `EncodingConstraint.EightBit`
// instead, although it never hurts to use `SevenBit`.
message.Prepare (EncodingConstraint.SevenBit);

message.Sign (signer, headers, headerAlgorithm, bodyAlgorithm);

// to write out the message so you have something to compare with:
var options = FormatOptions.Default.Clone ();
options.NewLineFormat = NewLineFormat.Dos;

message.WriteTo (options, "message.txt");
```

Then, once you have your DKIM-signed message, you can send it over SMTP using  [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) like so:

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
    // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s,c,h,e) => true;

    client.Connect ("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

    // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
    // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");

    // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
    client.Authenticate ("joey@gmail.com", "password");

    client.Send (message);
    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

Comment: I had a look again at the artical '3.4.3.  The "simple" Body Canonicalization Algorithm',  but I don't get any wiser from this.

What do you mean with "transform the body text using the Simple body canonicalization rules described in rfc6376, section 3.4.3. It looks to me like you are just tacking on a "\r\n" but that's not what the rules say to do."? 

The rules talk about empty white spaces and empty lines. In my body I only got this "helloleo". No empty lines at all or white spaces. "\r\n" are line breaks in plain text.
Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: When I create the DKIM bh (hash of content)

I'm hashing this content "helloleo" (also tried "helloleo\r\n" with a line-break) and with the Content-Transfer-Encoding type is "7bit". Then this should be working I thought. 

So therefor I thought there must be something wrong with how I'm hashing this content?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that your original question had the entire content of the MIME message (I thought the question only contained the raw DKIM-Signature header). So yes, since your signature was performed on `"helloleo\r\n"`, that should have worked (note:  you need the `"\r\n"`). I'm also assuming that the `'.'` at the end of the raw data is part of the termination sequence for the SMTP `DATA` command, right?

Comment: FWIW, the reason I said your code wasn't properly canonicalizing the content to sign was that all your code does is append `"\r\n"` which is not the way to canonicalize in the general sense. In your extremely basic test-case, yes, that's what you need to do, but that's not what you will need to do later once you start feeding this function *real world* message bodies.

Comment: Recommendation: Download a copy of MimeKit, copy my above code (making sure to load the proper private key file), and then compare the body hash that MimeKit generates with the body hash that your code generates.

Comment: About this question: I'm also assuming that the '.' at the end of the raw data is part of the termination sequence for the SMTP DATA command, right? Yes this is correct.

Comment: I did what you recommended and I see that the hash of the body of the MimeKit is very different then the one from mine. So there is something wrong when I'm hashing the body content "helloleo\r\n".

Comment: I manage to get the body hash the same as the MimeKit now. Thank you very much for you recommendation. Now after this change my email fails  completely for DKIM. I think this is because the header "b=" isn't correct.

Comment: Now you can compare the header signatures to MimeKit :)

Comment: BTW, what was the issue? Was the problem a bug in the DecodeRSAPrivateKey logic?

Comment: The problem was that I got confused with the gmail DKIM message. "dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)"

Comment: The problem was that I got confused with the gmail DKIM message. When I had the body content right the message was "dkim=fail" and when I had the hash body content wrong I got this message "dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)". So when I had the body content right I thought it was wrong, but because MimeKit has the same hash body as me the  "dkim=fail" must refer to the header hash instead. So the right thing to call was to us _privateKeySigner.Hash(defaultEncoding, SigningAlgorithm.RSASha1); Not _privateKeySigner.Sign() function.

Comment: Yes I can use MimeKit to find out what I'm doing wrong with Hashing the header content. In section "3.2.  Tag=Value Lists" it tells me "Unencoded semicolon (";") characters MUST NOT occur in  the tag value". But in the "DKIM-Signature" header there are quite a few in there. This is not a problem because MimeKit converts the value of the header to "UTF8"? And it also converts the header key to "ASCII". Am I correct in seeing this? Just seams so strange to me that the key and value uses different encoding's?

Comment: UTF-8 is a super-set of ASCII - I use ASCII for header *names* because they are very restricted to just US-ASCII. I use UTF-8 for the header *values* because MimeKit supports International Email Standards and so the header could also be in raw UTF-8. Technically it wouldn't matter if I used UTF-8 for the header names.

Comment: BTW, what it means when it says that `;` characters are not allowed in the tag value is not that `;`'s aren't allowed in the header value, they just aren't allowed in the *tag* value. In other words: `DKIM-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; tag=val;ue`  <-- this last `;`.

Comment: btw, this might be easier over email - feel free to email me instead if you want (my email address is listed on my github page).

Answer (score 1):

I would have commented instead, but my reputation is not yet high enough. :/

I am using PHPMailer, but in case my solution applies more generally, I thought I would leave a note.

My emails were triggering a `dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)` error AFTER I had already verified my email system and the DKIM keys in a test environment.

Turns out that for PHPMailer at least, if there is a trailing space at the end of the $body string which is being fed into `$mail->Body = $body;` then the DKIM body hashes won't match, thus triggering the error.